# API - Call the same method internally and externally

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, controller

I'm making an API with Express, which integrates two different platforms, like a bridge. Let's say I have a Products Controller, which has the default CRUD operations you expect.

Let's create a product. The normal way is to just create a route, auto-injecting req and res, like this:

```
app.post('/api/products', productsController.create)
```

In my controller, I would create a function like this:

```
const create = (req, res) =>
    ...
```

Calling this method externally would work because inside the function I would extract the parameters from the request and then create the product.

BUT, I have another route and another function which sync the products from one place to another, so I need to use productsController.create internally, but I can't use it because it expects the req and res for creating products.

Which is the best way to handle this?

I could change my controller function to accept just the treated fields, and then inside the route, I can treat the parameters and call the function. The only problem is that the routes will get a little bigger and uglier, while now it's just one line per route.

Or I could create another module for treating the fields and then calling the create function, like below. It's a little smaller inside the route, but still, uglier than just one line.

```
const create = product =>
    ...

app.post('/api/products', (req, res) => {
    let product = treatFields(req.params)
    productsController.create(product)
    // send the response
})
```

Anyway, does anyone know a good way of doing this?

Comment: The second way is better than the first. You should decouple the controller and the model. This will help you reuse your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In non-trivial Node.js APIs, you usually have a service layer in addition to controllers. So, controllers only extract parameters and maybe validate them sometimes. And your services layer does the business logic.

Something like this structure:

```
server/
    controllers/
        products-controller          - the REST router[1]
        something-else-controller    - another router[1]
    services/
        products-service             - the "business logic" [2]
```

Now, your routers (marked [1] above), they take parameters. E.g. to fetch a product, they take a product Id or product name:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const productsService = require('../services/products-service');
router.get('/products', (req, res, next) => {
    const count = req.query.count ;
    // maybe validate or something
    if (!count) {
        return next(new Error('count param mandatory'));
    }
    productsService.getAllProducts(count)
        .then(products => res.json(products))
        .catch(err => next(err));
});
router.get('/products/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    if (id.length !== whatever ) {
        return next(new Error('Id not lookin good'));
    }
    productsService.getProductById(id)
        .then(product => res.json(product))
        .catch(err => next(err));
});

// and "another" router file, maybe products in a category
router.get('/categories/:catId/products', (req, res, next) => {
    const catId = req.params.catId;
    productsService.getProductByCategory(catId)
        .then(products => res.json(products))
        .catch(err => next(err));
});
```

And your service layer does all the database logic and maybe "business" validation (e.g. makes sure emails are valid or product has a valid price when updating etc.):

```
const productService = {
    getAllProducts(count) {
        return database.find(/*whatever*/)
            .then(rawData => formatYourData(rawData)); // maybe strip private stuff, convert times to user's profile, whatever
            // important thing is that this is a promise to be used as above
    },
    getProductById(id) {
      if (!id) {
        // foo
        return Promise.reject(new Error('Whatever.'));
      }
      return database.findSomethingById(id)
          .then(rawData => formatData(rawData)); // more of the same

    },
    getProductByCategory() {
      return []:
    }
}
```

Now, I've mixed the param validation on both sides. If you want your REST ("web") layer cleaner, just pass the parameters without checking, e.g. `productService.getProducts(req.query.page, req.query.limit).then(result => res.json(result);`. And do more of the checking in your service.

I would frequently break down even my service down into serveral files, kind of like this:

```
services/
    product-service/
        index.js // "barrel" export file for the whole service
        get-product.js
        get-products.js
        create-product.js
        delete-product.js
        update-product.js
        product.-utilsjs  // common helpers, like the formatter thingy or mabye some db labels, constants and such, used in all of the service files.
```

This approach makes the whiole thing much more testable and readable. More files, though, but it's nothing compared to your usual node_modules unholly mess :)

Comment: Thank you so much, this looks good and clean. I will wait for more answers but I think I'll go with this one. Is it common to call it "services" or there are alternatives?

Comment: Well, it is relatively common, but there are different ways to addressing this. "Services" is probably something transfered over from Java world (they are doing backends for much longer than we with JavaScript and Node).

Answer (score 1):

First, controllers shouldn't be handling any business logic, they are meant to provide an interface for users to interact with your service and nothing more, they should only validate the interface itself (i.e. that the query or path parameters are set correctly and deciding the HTTP response code if there is an error). I would handle instead the logic to return a promise to do something like:

```
function createProduct(Product){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        // run your validations and if there is an error
        // if no error
        resolve(product.id);
        // else
        reject(MY_ERROR_REASON);
    });
}

// version 1
function createRoute(req, res){
    const product = treatFields(req.params)
    createProduct(product).then((id)=>{
        res.send(id);
    }).catch((e)=>{
        res.status(400).send(e);
    });
}

//version 2 (for node >7)
async function createRoute(req, res){
    const product = treatFields(req.params)
    try{
        const id = await createProduct(product);
        res.send(id);
    }
    catch(e){
        res.status(400).send(e);
    }
}

app.post('/api/products', productsController.createRoute);
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is more about the architecture. One possible option is you can follow the layered architecture and create following layers.

- **routes** 
  app.post('/api/products', productsController.create) ....
- **controllers**
   will be responsible to extract the params from request, validate and ask for services layer to perform the specific business and then respond back with the date from services layer (by using views/mappers)
- **services/facade**
  will be responsible to perform the specific business. For example in your case, the *bridge function* will communicate with other platforms from here. If required, Services layer will be communicating with models for DB operations.
- **models**
   will be responsible for DB operations.

Now you can call service's function from any controllers/tests. You can advance your application's architecture as much as you want.

NOTE: you can also merge routes and controller that we mostly do in Node projects.